# Camel: Add TypeConverter in Test Case

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hy,

I'm currently writing a TestCase in which, at some point, I need an automatic type conversion for a self written model object to String.
When executing the code "live" it works, because other components are initiated then, but in the testcase they are not, which is why I need to add the mock type convert in the test case.

This is what I did so far, but it does not seem to work, as the type conversion crashes (*org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: com.....MyClass to the required type: java.lang.String*)

```java
context // Autowired in the test class
    .getTypeConverterRegistry().addTypeConverters(new TypeConverters() {
  @Converter
  public String myClassToString(MyClass file) {
    if (file.getName().equals(expectedFileName)) {
      return fileContent;
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Unknown file for Mock TypeConverter: " + file.getName());
    }
  }
});
```

I'm not sure this is the correct way of adding a type converter without creating a dedicated class, but its what I found after so research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying some more things an actually understanding the exceptions that were thrown I found out, what I (probably) did wrong.

After some more trial and error I got the above code to be registered in the type converter registry with no changes to the type converter itself (not sure what I changed, maybe it was just some caching problem..)

When the converter finally got registered and executed by camel, I got this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

It seems like it is not possible to add a TypeConverter using an anonymous class (having Spring Boot as the runner) as Spring tries to inject some String there.
I was able to fix the problem by extracting the TypeConverter to an actual (not anonymous) class and then just adding an instance of that class to the registry.
Its also possible to do this with an inner class in the test, as long as it is public.
In any case it is important to have the actual conterter method be static, as Spring will otherwise throw the same error.

Not sure why all this happens, but at least I got it working in the end.
Maybe somebody can shed some light on Springs behavior, where it wants to inject a String, where there is nothing, that should be autowired.

Greets
Chris